# "in Friends" vs. "from Friends"

Tags: prepositions

I've gone through [Adverbs: types] and (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-types)
[ref2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position) on Cambridge Dictionary and I guess I understand the rules there.

Consider the following three sentences.

1. **In Friends**, Rachel Green is played by Jennifer Aniston.
2. Rachel Green **in Friends** is played by Jennifer Aniston.
3. Rachel Green **from Friends** is played by Jennifer Aniston.

According to those rules, sentence 1 is less common than sentence 2, though sentence 1 is not rare. All three of them are clear and natural, is my understanding correct?

Similarly, which one should I use in this sentence, "in" or "from"?

> Ross **from** Friends and Sheldon **from** The Big Bang Theory have some characteristics in common.

Comment: I wouldn't like to hazard a guess as to which is 'most common'. You would put the phrase "In _Friends_" first if you were talking about the TV series in general, perhaps going on to speak of other characters, In (2), it's used to explain which Rachel Green you are talking about.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Your comments are very helpful. How about (3)

Comment: Referring to an actor or character _from_ a TV drama is acceptable too.

Comment: I, and I think most AmE speakers, would strongly prefer *on 'Friends'* to *in 'Friends'*. One is *in* a feature film or play but *on* a radio or television show.

Comment: @choster Thank you. So, the suggestion is `on 'Friends'`, right?